# How do I find the integral of a distribution?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have the following distribution:

$\Delta (x)=\begin{Bmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
-x_2\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}&\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
0\\ 
-x_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$

and I have found that this distribution is involutive, and so it is also integrable for the Frobenius theorem. Now, I know that since it is integrable, it exists a $\lambda $ such that:

$\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x}\Delta (x)=0$

and so:

$\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_1}x_1-\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_2}x_2=0$

$\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_1}x_1-\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_3}x_3=0$

but now, how do I find $\lambda $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve such systems is given in the proof of the Frobenius theorem. The proof of sufficiency is constructive; it provides a way to construct a solution. There is, however, an easier way.

A system consisting of one equation can be solved using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).
Consider a system consisting of one (first) equation:
$$\tag{1}
\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_1}x_1-\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_2}x_2=0
$$
Note that on the left side of (1) there is nothing other than the derivative of  the function $\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ along the trajectories of an ode system
$$\tag{2}
\frac{dx_1}{dt}= x_1\qquad \frac{dx_2}{dt}= -x_2\qquad \frac{dx_3}{dt}= 0
$$
and $\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ satisfies (1) iff it is a first integral of (2).
Let's find the first integrals of(2).
$$
dt=\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{dx_2}{-x_2},\qquad dx_3=0
$$
gives us two first integrals
$$
\phi_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)= x_1 x_2,\qquad \phi_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)= x_3.
$$
The general solution of (1) consists of all first integrals of (2), i.e.
$$
\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)=F(\phi_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),\phi_2(x_1,x_2,x_3))= F(x_1x_2,x_3)
$$ 
where $F(\cdot,\cdot)$ is any function of the required order of continuity.

Substitute the obtained general solution into the second equation 
$$\tag{3}
\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_1}x_1-\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x_3}x_3=0.
$$
Let $\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)= F(u,v)$, $u=x_1x_2$, $v=x_3$. Using the chain rule one obtains
$$
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x_1}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} x_2
$$
($\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x_2}$ is not needed)
$$
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x_3}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_3}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}. 
$$
Substitution into (3) gives us
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} x_2x_1-\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}x_3=0
$$
$$\tag{4}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} u-\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}v=0
$$
The equation (4) can also be solved using the method of characteristics:
$$
\frac{du}{u}=\frac{dv}{-v}
$$
implies that 
$$
F(u,v)= G(uv),
$$
where $G(\cdot)$ is any function of the required order of continuity.
So, the general solution to the original system is $\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)= G(x_1x_2x_3)$.

Comment: thank you a lot for answering. I have been analyzing the procedure but I still cannot understand. I searched also for the procedure with the Frobenius theorem, and it calculates the fluxes of vector field to do so, but I don't understand how. In your procedure, how did you arrive at the point of saying that $\Phi _1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1x_2$ and $\Phi _2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_3$? Thank you again.

Comment: @J.D. $x_3$ is a first integral because $\dot x_3=0$ implies that $x_3$ doesn't change along the trajectories of the system (2). After we noticed this, we can exclude $x_3$ from consideration and solve the truncated system $\frac{dx_1}{dt}= x_1$, $\frac{dx_2}{dt}= -x_2$. This gives us another first integral $x_1x_2$ because $x_1x_2=C$ is a solution of the truncated system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a general procedure to solve this kind of problems, but here you can see that the two generating vector fields are tangent to the level sets of the function $\lambda=\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1x_2x_3$.

This means it solves both the equations you have and hence an integral submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where your distribution is pointwise tangent) can be written in the form
$$\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)=c\} $$

P.S. I've found it just by checking the structure of the fields, not by direct solution of your 2 PDEs

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please explain to me how did you get that $\lambda $ has that value? Sorry if I ask , but I cannot understand how it can be deduced from the structure of the field.-

Comment: In general I think it is not a trivial problem at all. In fact what you are asking is a first integral of both the fields and it is usually a complicated task to explicitly find a first integral of a field, supposing its existence. What I suggest you to do is to try looking for solutions with splitted variables, so of the form $\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)=a(x_1)b(x_2)c(x_3)$ (which works in your case with $a=b=c=id$, or with $\lambda(x_1,x_2,x_3)=a(x_1)+b(x_2)+c(x_3)$, so that the system of PDEs becomes a system of ODEs which is probably easier.