# Problem understanding how to integrate a distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I am trying to integrate a distribution, but I am having some problems understanding how. I am trying to replicate the following exercise:

[image]

and the solution is the one at the bottom.

The problem is that it does not explains how to find the values for $\lambda $ and I cant't really understand how it has been found. I have been on this for long, and I have posed already a question on this, which is [How do I find the integral of a distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650181/how-do-i-find-the-integral-of-a-distribution) , but I have deicided to pose another question, since I have not understood how to solve this kind of problems, sorry for that.

So, the original distribution is:

$\Delta =span\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
x_3
\end{pmatrix} & 
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{x^2}\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$

and so, I have to find he values of $\lambda $ for which:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{d\lambda }{dx_1} &\frac{d\lambda }{dx_2}  &\frac{d\lambda }{dx_3}  & \frac{d\lambda }{dx_4}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & e^{x^2}\\ 
 1& 0\\ 
 0& 0\\ 
 x_3& 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

Can somebody please help me understand?

Comment: Notice the matrix multiplication doesn’t even make sense. Please state the actual distribution for starters.

Comment: Oh, the notation *does* make sense. I just didn't stop to parse it sensibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking, locally, for *level hypersurfaces* of the functions $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ whose intersection will give the distribution. Thus, the normal vectors $\nabla\lambda_1$ and $\nabla\lambda_2$ must  be orthogonal to the vectors spanning the distribution.

There's not much point having the $e^{x_2}$ (note your typo) in the second vector. The vector $(1,0,0,0)$ will do just fine. So $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ should be *independent* of the variable $x_1$. Orthogonality to the vector $(x_1,1,0,x_3)$ then reduces to orthogonality to the vector $(0,1,0,x_3)$. Linear algebra tells us that the gradient vectors must therefore be in the span of $(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,-x_3,0,1)$, so we take $\lambda_1(x) = x_3$ and $\lambda_2(x)=x_4-x_2x_3$ (Hint: Change the second vector so that mixed partials will match).

**REMARK**: My favorite way to approach these integrability problems is to use the differential forms version of Frobenius integrability. In particular, the distribution is given by $\omega_1=0$, $\omega_2=0$, where $\omega_1 = dx_3$ and $\omega_2 = x_3\,dx_2-dx_4$. Since $d\omega_1=0$ and $d\omega_2 = dx_3\wedge dx_2 = \omega_1\wedge dx_2$, the system is integrable. Indeed, if we consider $\tilde\omega_2 = \omega_2+x_2\omega_1 = x_3\,dx_2 - dx_4 + x_2\,dx_3 = d(x_2x_3-x_4)$, we see that the distribution is given by taking level surfaces of $\lambda_1=x_3$ and $\lambda_2 = x_2x_3-x_4$.